# Помогите работяге дописать jquery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста для `iframe#video_link` заменить `src`, чтобы в `src` выводилась строка, выводимая сейчас в алерт

```
<iframe id="video_link" width="210" height="160" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sampleUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zIM-PIItf4";
    var video_id = sampleUrl.split("v=")[1].substring(0, 11);
    var finishUrl = ('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video_id);       
    alert (finishUrl);
    $("#video_link").attr("src","???");
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#video_link").attr("src",finishUrl);`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, пробовал так но не работало! Сейчас заработало нормально.

Comment: Работает же https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/a9tf9pyb/

Comment: @br3t Прекрасно работает, видимо я в прошлый раз где-то ошибку в синтаксисе допустил.

Comment: @br3t Извиняюсь за беспокойство, только начал осваивать jquery. Не поможете еще с таким моментом? Нижеприведенный код генерится на страничке много раз, соответственно возникает проблема с присвоением значения атрибута src к iframe. Всем сгенерированным iframe присваивается одно и тоже значение атрибута src. Может быть как-то в скрипте менять значение id каждого нового iframe? (Значение sampleUrl у меня берется из <?=$arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PATH"]["VALUE"]?>)

Comment: Как определять, какому фрейму какой src присвоить?

Comment: @br3t Не могу толком сформулировать задачу, соответственно и решение найти не получается. Ладно, буду думать, а то написал какой-то бред. Еще раз извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема. Это самая простая работа с переменными.

```js
    var sampleUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zIM-PIItf4";
    var video_id = sampleUrl.split("v=")[1].substring(0, 11);
    var finishUrl = ('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video_id);       
    alert (finishUrl);
    $("#video_link").attr("src",finishUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="video_link" width="210" height="160" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```